# Objective-c remove percent symbol from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, symbols

If I have a string like so: "55%"

Why is this not picking up the percent symbol:

```
- (NSString*) stripPercentageSymbols : (NSString*) strToClean {

    //check to see if the number is already formatted correctly
    NSRange percentSignCheck = [strToClean rangeOfString:@"%%"];

    //only strip it if it has the %
    if (percentSignCheck.location != NSNotFound) {

        NSLog(@"ok");

        NSString* cleanedString = [strToClean substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, strToClean.length-2)];

        return cleanedString;
    }

    return nil;

}
```

Comment: what about: @"%d%%" notation?

Comment: What is the output when you call this method?

Comment: Did you try finding the range of just @"%" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSRange percentSignCheck = [strToClean rangeOfString:@"%%"];
```

is incorrect, you don't have any format strings at all here. You want

```
NSRange percentSignCheck = [strToClean rangeOfString:@"%"];
```

instead.

Also, the range you are clipping the string to is wrong as well. It strips the first character along with the trailing percent symbol. This line:

```
NSString* cleanedString = [strToClean substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, strToClean.length-2)];
```

should be

```
NSString* cleanedString = [strToClean substringToIndex:strToClean.length - 1;]
```

instead.

---

By the way, why are you tricking around with ranges and stuff? It would be sufficient to just

```
return [strToClean stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%" withString:@""];
```

instead.

Comment: I must of been doing something else wrong when I tried just @"%", it worked this time. Im using ranges because if there is no % symbol I need to do other stuff. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PruitIgoe Another thing is that the range specification is wrong. See update.

Comment: I know, I picked that up on the output. : D